# What's the difference between using INDEX vs KEY in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, indexing, key

I know how to use INDEX as in the following code. And I know how to use *foreign key* and *primary key*.

```sql
CREATE TABLE tasks ( 

    task_id        int unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, 
    parent_id      int unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT 0, 
    task           varchar(100) NOT NULL, 
    date_added     timestamp    NOT NULL, 
    date_completed timestamp        NULL, 

    PRIMARY KEY ( task_id ), 
    INDEX parent ( parent_id )
)
```

However I found a code using `KEY` instead of `INDEX` as following.

```sql
CREATE TABLE orders (
    
    order_id        int unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    -- etc 

    KEY order_date ( order_date )
)
```

I could not find any explanation on the official MySQL page. Could anyone tell me what is the differences between `KEY` and `INDEX`?

The only difference I see is that when I use `KEY ...`,  I need to repeat the word, e.g. `KEY order_date ( order_date )`.

Answer (score 343, accepted):

There's no difference. They are synonyms, though `INDEX` should be preferred (as `INDEX` is ISO SQL compliant, while `KEY` is a MySQL-specific, non-portable, extension).

From [the `CREATE TABLE` manual entry](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/create-table.html#:%7E:text=KEY%20%7C%20INDEX):

> `KEY` is normally a synonym for `INDEX`. The key attribute `PRIMARY KEY` can also be specified as just `KEY` when given in a column definition. This was implemented for compatibility with other database systems.

---

By *"The key attribute `PRIMARY KEY` can also be specified as just `KEY` when given in a column definition."*, it means that these three `CREATE TABLE` statements below **are equivalent** and generate identical `TABLE` objects in the database:

```sql
CREATE TABLE orders1 (
    order_id int PRIMARY KEY
);

CREATE TABLE orders2 (
    order_id int KEY
);

CREATE TABLE orders3 (
    order_id int NOT NULL,

    PRIMARY KEY ( order_id )
);
```

...while these 2 statements *below* (for `orders4`, `orders5`) are equivalent with each other, **but not** with the 3 statements above, as here `KEY` and `INDEX` are synonyms for `INDEX`, not a `PRIMARY KEY`:

```
CREATE TABLE orders4 (
    order_id int NOT NULL,

    KEY ( order_id )
);

CREATE TABLE orders5 (
    order_id int NOT NULL,

    INDEX ( order_id )
);
```

...as the `KEY ( order_id )` and `INDEX ( order_id )` members **do not** define a `PRIMARY KEY`, they only define a generic `INDEX` object, which is nothing like a `KEY` at all (as it does not uniquely identify a row).

As can be seen by running `SHOW CREATE TABLE orders1...5`:

| Table | `SHOW CREATE TABLE...` |
| --- | --- |
| `orders1` | `CREATE TABLE orders1 (` `order_id int NOT NULL,` `PRIMARY KEY ( order_id )` `)` |
| `orders2` | `CREATE TABLE orders2 (` `order_id int NOT NULL,` `PRIMARY KEY ( order_id )` `)` |
| `orders3` | `CREATE TABLE orders3 (` `order_id int NOT NULL,` `PRIMARY KEY ( order_id )` `)` |
| `orders4` | `CREATE TABLE orders4 (` `order_id int NOT NULL,` `KEY ( order_id )` `)` |
| `orders5` | `CREATE TABLE orders5 (` `order_id int NOT NULL,` `KEY ( order_id )` `)` |

Comment: When looking at table info in the latest version of SQLYog it shows `KEY keyname (column_name)` when I created the table with `INDEX keyname (column_name)`. The fact that it is a synonym explains it perfectly.

Comment: "The key attribute `PRIMARY KEY` can also be specified as just `KEY` when given in a column definition."  
What does this mean?

Comment: "The key attribute `PRIMARY KEY` can also be specified as just KEY when given in a column definition." please explain how?.

Comment: @Zyl I've updated this answer to answer your question.

Comment: @NaeemUlWahhab I've updated this answer to answer your question.

Answer (score 15):

Here is a [nice description](http://discuss.fogcreek.com/joelonsoftware5/default.asp?cmd=show&ixPost=152398) about the "difference":

> "MySQL requires every Key also be indexed, that's an implementation
>   detail specific to MySQL to improve performance."

Comment: Question is about the use of SQL Identifiers KEY and INDEX in MySQL. Not the difference between a key and an index.

Comment: I searched for the difference with a search engine and this was the first result. In my opinion there is no need to open an extra question. But feel free to do so if you want to.

Answer (score 10):

Keys are special fields that play very specific roles within a table, and the type of key determines its purpose within the table.

An index is a structure that RDBMS(database management system) provides to improve data processing. An index has nothing to do with a logical database structure.

SO...

Keys are logical structures you use to identify records within a table and indexes are physical structures you use to optimize data processing.

Source: Database Design for Mere Mortals

Author: Michael Hernandez

Comment: Question is about the use of SQL Identifiers KEY and INDEX in MySQL. Not the difference between a key and an index.

Comment: Really?! I read the question differently, and this answer in my opinion is the only one that states what's the difference right.

Answer (score 7):

It is mentioned as a synonym for `INDEX` in the 'create table' docs:
[MySQL 5.5 Reference Manual :: 13 SQL Statement Syntax :: 13.1 Data Definition Statements :: 13.1.17 CREATE TABLE Syntax](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/create-table.html)

@Nos already cited the section and linked the help for 5.1.

Like `PRIMARY KEY` creates a primary key and an index for you,
`KEY` creates an index only.

Answer (score 0):

A key is a set of columns or expressions on which we build an index.

1. While an index is a structure that is stored in database, keys are strictly a       logical concept.
2. Index help us in fast accessing a record, whereas keys just identify the records uniquely.
3. Every table will necessarily have a key, but having an index is not mandatory.

Check on https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e40540/indexiot.htm#CNCPT721

Comment: Question is about the use of SQL Identifiers KEY and INDEX in MySQL. Not the difference between a key and an index.

Comment: @Josh J Even if the original motivation was to ask about identifiers, searching for the difference about a key and an index with a search engine yields this topic. It could make sense to improve the title of the question to be more specific. On the other hand, writing a question about the difference between a key and an index in mysql would be possibly marked as a duplicate. =>I find such complementary answers very useful. The "real" answer will get the highest score, anyway. So I do not see a reason for negative votes on complementary answers.

Comment: I have capitalized INDEX and KEY in the question to make this clear.