# SQL Server Index Naming Conventions

Tags: sql-server, naming-conventions, indexing

Is there some standard way to name indexes for SQL Server?  It seems that the primary key index is named PK_ and non-clustered indexes typically start with IX_.  Are there any naming conventions beyond that for unique indexes?

Answer (score 394, accepted):

I use

PK_ for primary keys

UK_ for unique keys

IX_ for non clustered non unique indexes

UX_ for unique indexes

All of my index name take the form of
`<index or key type>_<table name>_<column 1>_<column 2>_<column n>`

Comment: What about nonunique clustered indexes? CX?

Comment: I've never had a need for a non unique clustered index ... I realize that it is possible, but it has never seemed to be the correct course of action to me.

Comment: According to the answer given here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1401572/what-are-differences-between-index-v-s-key-in-mysql KEY and INDEX are synonyms. So it should be no need to have different prefixes for unique keys and unique indexes?

Comment: Its a logical difference, I use UniqueKey if there will be a foreign key reference, otherwise I use a UniqueIndex.

Comment: Why include the table name when two tables can have the same index name? i.e. uniqueness is not needed.

Comment: Tahir Hassan: I think you are mistaken, Sql Server indexes must have a unique name.  In addition, I like being able to look at the index name and see which table or view it belongs to.

Comment: I'd replace "UK" and "UX" with "UQ", UniQue.

Comment: Just googled this question while looking for proper convention for non-unique clustered...  And the are still no answer :(

Comment: I came here on the same query. We have them a lot as pretty much all our PK are all UUID's but currently all of them are IX_ which doesn't feel right to me. I'm going to go for CX like Chris suggested! :)

Comment: If table names in the database happen to have underscores in them (as you might find if you are working with a framework such as Ruby on Rails), I add an extra underscore after the table name:  IX_table_name__col1_col2    And if column names have underscores, I might add an extra underscore between them as well.

Comment: What about included columns? Do you include them in the naming format?

Comment: Using the type of index in the name of the index seems like an anti-pattern.

Answer (score 35):

I usually name indexes by the name of the table and the columns they contain:

```
ix_tablename_col1_col2
```

Comment: How do you differentiate between index columns and included columns?

Comment: I'm pretty sure that he's only listing the Indexed columns, in the order that they're being placed in the index.

Comment: I use it as follows: IX_TableName_col1_col2-includecol1-includecol2

Answer (score 13):

Is it worth a special prefix for indices associated with foreign keys?  I think so, since it reminds me that indices on foreign keys are not created by default, and so it is easier to see if they are missing.

For this, I am using names that match the name of the foreign key:

```
FK_[table]_[foreign_key_table]
```

or, where multiple foreign keys exist on the same table

```
FK_[table]_[foreign_key_table]_[foreign_key_field]
```

Answer (score 1):

I know a old topic but thought I'd throw in my 2cents worth

- PKC_      Primary Key, Clustered
- PKNC_     Primary Key, Non Clusterd
- NCAK_     Non Clustered, Unique
- CAK_      Clustered, Unique
- NC_       Non Clustered

Example;

NCAK_AccountHeader_OrganisationID_NextDate

Where NCAK : Non Clustered, Unique, AccountHeader : Table and OrganisationID_NextDate : Columns.

Comment: Alternate key - http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unique_key#Alternate_key