# SQL: What is does the UNIQUE mean when creating a primary key

Tags: sql

I've got a table called students:

```
+------------+------------+-----------+---------------------+---------------------+
| student_id | first_name | surname   | email               | reg_date            |  
+------------+------------+-----------+---------------------+---------------------+
|          1 | Emily      | Jackson   | emilyj@gmail.com    | 2012-10-14 11:14:13 |
|          2 | Daniel     | ALexander | daniela@hotmail.com | 2014-08-19 08:08:23 |
|          3 | Sarah      | Bell      | sbell@gmail.com     | 1998-07-04 13:16:32 |
|          4 | Alex       | Harte     | AHarte@hotmail.com  | 1982-06-14 00:00:00 |
+------------+------------+-----------+---------------------+---------------------+
```

When creating the table:

```
CREATE TABLE students(
-> student_id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
-> first_name VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
-> surname VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
-> email VARCHAR(200) NOT NULL,
-> reg_date DATETIME NOT NULL,
-> PRIMARY KEY (student_id),
-> UNIQUE (email));
```

What does the 'UNIQUE (email)' mean? Does it mean if the primary key isn't unique, look at the email to see if that's unique instead? Or something different?

Thanks

Comment: it means that any particular value in that field can appear only ONCE in the entire table. that means you can't have two+ users with `president@whitehouse.gov` as their address.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Difference between Key, Primary Key, Unique Key and Index in MySQL](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3844899/difference-between-key-primary-key-unique-key-and-index-in-mysql)

Comment: @Marc, you should post that as an answer.

Comment: In this case, shouldn't the email just be primary key?  your student id will always be unique because it's auto_increment.  Just a thought.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `UNIQUE` keyword creates a unique constraint on the columns that are mentioned in its argument list (in this case, `email`). It does not interfere with the primary key. It will enforce unique values on the email column, that is, fail with an exception when a row is about to be `INSERT`ed (or `UPDATE`d) that would collide with an existing row.

A primary key (by default) implies a unique constraint. So as you designate student_id as your primary key, the RDBMS will also automatically maintain unique values in that column for you.

Further reading: http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_unique.asp

Answer (score 1):

It allows the engine to use it as an index in queries and enforces it to be unique when a record/s are inserted/updated; throwing a violation of a `unique key constraint` when an already existing `email` is inserted/updated.

Example: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/7a0aee

More Information: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/partitioning-limitations-partitioning-keys-unique-keys.html