# How to create a database table for when in the Primary key column there is repeat values?

Tags: android, mysql, database, relational-database

I am trying to store different WEIGHTS User's Upload on Different DATES, and when the weights are uploaded they will correspond to a primary ID which is "Username"

So this is what i have a picture of my table looking like

Username(PrimaryKEY)---------- Date  ------------ Weight

George------------------------------24/09/2016---------82

Tom-----------------------------------24/09/2016---------85

Harry-----------------------------------24/09/2016--------82

George------------------------------25/09/2016---------83

Tom----------------------------------25/09/2016---------86

Harry---------------------------------25/09/2016--------83

If anyone had any ideas how i could do this differently or infact if this would actually work please let me know, Thanks!

Comment: Store usernames as PK in a separate table and refer the column as FK in this table, also have a separate id column in this table which will be PK.

Comment: Typically you'd have two tables e.g. User and Readings with the latter referencing the former. Alternately make the primary key the username and the date.

Comment: Generally bad practice to use string type columns as primary key, because they MUST be unique. Instead use an autoincrimented numeric column type, THEN you could add a 2 column UNIQUE index on Username & Date for example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would have a separate table for users.

```
CREATE TABLE `user` (
  `id` INTEGER UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `username` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
  `firstname` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
  `lastname` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
);

CREATE TABLE `weight` (
  `id` INTEGER UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `weight` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
  `date` DATETIME NOT NULL,
  `username` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  CONSTRAINT `username` FOREIGN KEY `username` (`id`)
    REFERENCES `user` (`id`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION
)
```

This above tables are created with following rules

1. Foreign key is set to id in user table. If you want to change it to username, change it to. `CONSTRAINT username FOREIGN KEY username(username).`
2. On delete is no action so even if a user is deleted the weight record will still be there. If you want to change that, then change on delete to cascade. so if a user is deleted, the weight record by that user will also be deleted.

Comment: Thank you for your response! Cleared things up now in my head!

Answer (score 1):

You have to understand the nature of your DB table before deciding what column(s) should be chosen to be the primary key.

Here is a definition of **Primary Key** from [Techopedia](https://www.techopedia.com/definition/5547/primary-key):

> A primary key is a special relational database table column (or
>   combination of columns) designated to uniquely identify all table
>   records.
>
> A primary key’s main features are:
>
> - It must contain a unique value for each row of data.
> - It cannot contain
>     null values.
>
> A primary key is either an existing table column or a
>   column that is specifically generated by the database according to a
>   defined sequence.

In this case, it seems like your table is storing *measurement* information about a user, who is allowed to have multiple measurements on different days (e.g. `George` had a measurement on `24/09/2016` and then another one again on `25/09/2016`), but not on the same day.

In this case, the primary key really should have two columns -- `Username` and `Date`.

Do not confuse primary key from unique key or just key (index).  Here is an [SO discussion about the topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3844899/difference-between-key-primary-key-unique-key-and-index-in-mysql).

By the way, if you want to further allow the same user to upload more than one measurements on the same day, then you have two solutions:

1. Add a **surrogate** key column (probably called `id`) that uniquely 
    identifies each measurement records (see Wikipedia discussion).  Use
    this surrogate key as the primary key of your table.
2. Make your `Date` column a type of `Datetime` rather than just `Date`. 
    You still have to limit that there can be no more than one
    measurements from the same user for any given `Datetime` value (in `MySQL`
    the data type of `DATETIME` support fractional second (up to 
    microseconds precision))

Personally I think the approach of using a surrogate key is the safest in the long run.

Comment: PK = UNIQUE NOT NULL.