# Why am I allowed to have more than 767 bytes for utf8mb4 encoded MariaDB (version 10.1.35) index prefix in this case?

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, database, mariadb, prefix

I have read [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1814532/1071-specified-key-was-too-long-max-key-length-is-767-bytes) and I try to test it in my case, but I don't understand why it work.

I'm using rails and utf8mb4 encoded MariaDB (version 10.1.35)

I have this in my schema:

```
  create_table "settings", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string   "var",         limit: 255,   null: false
    t.text     "value",       limit: 65535
    t.integer  "target_id",   limit: 4,     null: false
    t.string   "target_type", limit: 255,   null: false
    t.datetime "created_at",                null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at",                null: false
  end

  add_index "settings", ["target_type", "target_id", "var"],
       name: "index_settings_on_target_type_and_target_id_and_var",
       unique: true,
       length: {"target_type"=>191,
                "target_id"=>nil,
                "var"=>191}, using: :btree
```

I do `rake db:schema:load` and it pass without any problem. I think it should show error because innoDB index prefix limit is 767 bytes and we exceed the limit in this case:

191*4 + 191*4 = 1528 which exceed 767

Can anybody explain why it still work?

I'm struggling to understand the difference between index, key for index and prefix in index. It would be nice if someone can list a resource for me to learn these too.

What I have read:

- https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/create-index.html#create-index-column-prefixes
- https://github.com/turnkeylinux/tracker/issues/985
- https://stackoverflow.com/a/3844913/6359753
- https://www.wikiwand.com/en/Database_index

Comment: have you already populate the table or is just created empty..?

Comment: I haven't populate the table

Comment: the real occupied  space in calculated  when you add  the data ..  .. in not checked before

Comment: I think it does check before populating data - If I change one of 191 to 192, then it fail with error when I do `rake db:schema:load`, I want to understand why it works with two 191

Comment: Please show us the `SHOW CREATE TABLE` from MySQL; some of us don't know how to decipher the stuff you provided.

Answer (score 0):

Index  is the object that mantain the info  for direct (or better access ) to rows .. for this the indexes store columns values the columns involved in indexes are named key  ..  the index prefix is a part (left side string) of the value in key for reduce the space for index .. ( if the prefix is always the same is unuseful )

```
191 x 4 = 764 (< 767)

192 x 4 = 768 (> 767)
```

the value 767  is per key and not total

> Prefix support and lengths of prefixes (where supported) are storage
>   engine dependent. For example, a prefix can be up to 767 bytes long
>   for InnoDB tables

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/create-index.html

so 191x4 for key `target_type`  and 191x4 for key `var` work

Comment: Can you please explain more about what index, key, prefix mean? And also I want to understand why it works with two 191. (I know that with one 192 will produce error because it exceed the 767 limit for innoDB, but don't know why two 191 will still work)

Comment: I'm confused when reading this sentence "for this the indexes store columns values the columns involved in indexes are named key", can you please explain column values and key separately? And also explain how they related to the index?

Comment: For this sentence "the index prefix is a part (left side string) of the value in key for reduce the space for index", it seems like you are saying index contain key, can you give an example of index that contain index to demonstrate this please?

Comment: Sorry to be a pain but I don't really understand after reading your answer. If you know of any resource I can read to better understand the context and the problem, please point me to it too. Thank you!

Comment: Index  contain values that are related  to columns  table  the columns involved in index  are named  keys ...  so is impossible show an example of index than contain index  ... an index  is based on key column  and contain the value of these columns  ..

Answer (score 0):

*Each* column of the index is limited to 767 bytes.

Try to avoid index prefixing (eg, `INDEX(foo(191)`), it is close to useless.  See [*this*](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/limits#767_limit_in_innodb_indexes) for several workarounds.

Is this what the index looks like?

```
UNIQUE(target_type(191), target_id, var(191))
```

If so, there is another problem.  The uniqueness constraint *ignores* the characters after the first 191 in `target_type` and `var`.  So, you are probably not getting what you expected.