# Difference SHOW INDEX, SHOW INDEXES and SHOW KEYS in MySQL

Tags: mysql, database

What's the difference between the SHOW INDEX, the SHOW INDEXES and the SHOW KEYS command in MySQL? If any. I get the same results.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[MySQL Doc](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/show-index.html)

They are synonyms.

Comment: Yes, I read this already. But that's no explanation why there are three commands for the same query. My question is: are there really no differences? Why then three commands?

Comment: It's not 3 commands. It's the same command with 3 names. You did not ask for an explanation. You asked if they are the same. Some RDBMS call indexes keys, so to ease transition there is show keys and show index/indexes.

Comment: Okay 3 "names". But I think it's rather confusing. And "to ease transition": but then why "INDEX" and "INDEXES"?

Answer (score 2):

As per MySQL documentations it is same :-

```
SHOW {INDEX | INDEXES | KEYS}
    {FROM | IN} tbl_name
    [{FROM | IN} db_name]
```

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/4.1/en/show-index.html

Comment: Also it seems to be duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1401572/what-are-differences-between-index-v-s-key-in-mysql

Comment: Not a duplicate of that question, as this question asks about a specific command and the linked question asks about indexes and keys in general.

Comment: But waanders is not responsding to anyone ------

Comment: The question is only 40 minutes old, a little patience ;) +1 for being 20 seconds faster :D

Comment: :) ----------- Am afraid they will mark as a personal conversation