# Difference b/w Constraint ... unique & Constraint ... primary

Tags: sql

I am a bit confused :

```
CREATE TABLE suppliers
( supplier_id numeric(10) not null,
  supplier_name varchar2(50) not null,
  contact_name varchar2(50),
  CONSTRAINT suppliers_pk Unique (supplier_id,supplier_name)

);

insert into suppliers values(1,'farhan','sohail');
insert into suppliers values(1,'farhanAnsar','sohail');



CREATE TABLE supplier
( supplier_id numeric(10) not null,
  supplier_name varchar2(50) not null,
  contact_name varchar2(50),
  CONSTRAINT supplier_pk PRIMARY KEY (supplier_id,supplier_name)
);

insert into supplier values(1,'sname','cname');
insert into supplier values(1,'suppName','cname');
```

Both works fine. Then What exactly is the difference b/w them?

Can someone elaborate?

Few more things :

A table can have only one primary key. Combination of 2 or more columns can be used as a primary key, but primary keyword cannot be used on 2 separate columns? Am i correct?

Comment: Yes, you are correct.
Also, if any of the posts helped please don't forget to upvote and/or mark one as an answer.

Comment: In the second part you have the contact_name not the supplier_name i the unique constraint. The suppliername is different in both examples. But the contact name is the same. So you got an dupplicate key.

Answer (score 0):

There can only be one Primary key whereas there can be multiple Unique keys. A Primary key is sort of a subset of Unique keys and has further restrictions on it e.g. cannot be null. Unique keys can still be used to identify records uniquely though.

Here's more:
[difference between primary key and unique key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9565996/difference-between-primary-key-and-unique-key)

Answer (score 0):

The differences are mentioned here.
[difference between primary key and unique key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9565996/difference-between-primary-key-and-unique-key)

Adding to it, in SQL Server, by default Primary Key creates a clustered index while Unique constraint creates a non-clustered index on the columns. This default behavior can be changed if needed.

Answer (score -1):

The Biggest Difference between primary key constraint and unique key constraint is:

> Primary key constraint not allowed to hold NULL value . Unique key constraint can hold only one
>   NULL value.

Thats it!

Comment: There's no mention of a Foreign key.

Comment: typo mistake. edited.

Comment: the "only one NULL value" part is wrong. (Well, it is partially correct and only in SQL-Server which has not implemented the SQL standard in this aspect.)