# How to create an int column without primary key?

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin, primary-key

I work in phpmyadmin where I have a sql table with the following columns:

```
image_id, int(11), AUTO_INCREMENT, Primary key, Unique
image_name, text
photographer, text
collection, text
```

When i try to add a new `int` column to the table which I want to call `image_order` I always end up with it getting attributes: `primary key and unique`.

What am I doing wrong since I get the unwanted primary key? Can I somehow remove the primary key so I can enter duplicate values?

Answer (score 0):

If your table is

```
create table images
(
  image_id int(11) AUTO_INCREMENT Primary key,
  image_name text,
  photographer text,
  collection text
);
```

then just use this to add your column

```
alter table images
add column image_order int
```

#### [SQLFiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/9c306/1)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not seeing that behavior. You're presumably not selecting anything from the "Index" dropdown when creating? What phpMyAdmin version do you have?

I've started with a table as you describe, then go to the Structure tab and "Add 1 column at the end of table" and press go.

On that page, I type in the "Name" 'image_order', I don't need to change the "Type" because the default is INT. No need to change anything else:

[image: Add column dialog]

That gives the expected result:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `stackdemo` (
`image_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `image_name` text NOT NULL,
  `photographer` text NOT NULL,
  `collection` text NOT NULL,
  `image_order` int(11) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=1 ;

ALTER TABLE `stackdemo`
 ADD PRIMARY KEY (`image_id`), ADD UNIQUE KEY `image_id` (`image_id`);

ALTER TABLE `stackdemo`
MODIFY `image_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT;
```

Show us exactly how you're creating the additional column in case there's something strange there, but it seems to work fine for me.

Also, you probably don't need the UNIQUE *and* PRIMARY key defined; PRIMARY is probably all you need here. See for instance [difference between primary key and unique key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9565996/difference-between-primary-key-and-unique-key) for some more details.