# In what situation would I be forced to use primary key or a unique key?

Tags: sql, primary-key, unique-key

I've googled about the differences between pk and uk. I've read QA on stackoverflow regarding the pk and uk.

Can please anyone in simple terms briefly tell me in what situation would i be preferring pk over uk or vice -versa.

Regards,
Ankit

Comment: http://dba.stackexchange.com/q/20204/5203, http://dba.stackexchange.com/q/15572/5203

Comment: also, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9565996/difference-between-primary-key-and-unique-key

Comment: The implementation of primary keys varies by database, so the relative merits of unique indexes versus primary keys depends on the database engine.

Answer (score 1):

If your column has all the distinct values and all not null values, use primary key and if it can insert only one null value along with all other distinct values, consider using unique key.

Comment: The ANSI standard allows multiple `NULL` values with a unique constraint, although not all databases support this.