# MySQL UNIQUE and INDEX use on Column

Tags: mysql, indexing, unique-index

I would like to add a index for quick lookups and uniqueness for a column called "Username".  I see an option to choose `UNIQUE` or `INDEX`.  Should I create both, or just go with UNIQUE?

I am not using username as a primary key guys.

Comment: I would assume that UNIQUE doesnt create an index like INDEX would for quick lookups.

Comment: You would assume incorrectly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`UNIQUE` creates an `INDEX` automatically for most dbs. So to answer you, you should create just one, which is `UNIQUE`. You can find a relevant thread [here](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/2783/does-making-a-field-unique-make-it-indexed) for MySQL

Answer (score 2):

In MySQL under the hood whenever you make an attribute `UNIQUE` it will be `INDEX`-ed too. Some database designer like to explicitly define `UNIQUE` attributes also as `INDEX`, but whatever your choice the result will be the same.

Comment: A unique makes it both, but indexing wont make it unique. So both the results wont be the same.

Comment: Yeah you are right, but he asked what is the best thing to do for an unique element so I assume you will need to use `UNIQUE` either way, but if he want to add `INDEX` is his choice. I will rephrase my answer to be even more clear ... tnx

Answer (score 0):

A primary key on a table is also automatically an index in mySql. So if you want to have a column be an index, and a unique key, then you can create a table like this:

```
 CREATE TABLE `users` (
    `username`,
     PRIMARY KEY (`username`),
     UNIQUE KEY `new_mmp_id` (`username`)
 ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
```

So in the end, you have an index on the `username` field that is a unique field itself. It is also the primary key, which is an index automatically. You never explained the specific fields in the table, like if you need an auto incremental id field

`Should I create both, or just go with UNIQUE?`

If you must have unique fields on the `username` column, then you should def. create both, if not then just set the username to the primary key which is an index.

I suggest your read this article
http://www.xaprb.com/blog/2009/09/12/the-difference-between-a-unique-index-and-primary-key-in-mysql/

[What are differences between Index v.s. Key in MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1401572/what-are-differences-between-index-v-s-key-in-mysql)

Comment: you are explaining to him what UNIQUE does and nothing on indexing (prior to your edit). The OP was asking which to choose in his case which u din answer. Moreover, even after edit, I feel a link which talks about differences between indexes and keys is not a proper answer.

Comment: Also I believe if you make an attribute a `PRIMARY KEY` it's `UNIQUE` by default.

Comment: I usuallly use UNIQUE key in order to also have an auto incremental ID field on a table. It means that the ID field is the primary key, but also the username field is unique so no other rows can have a combination of an existing id field and username field

Comment: Who said Im using the username as a primary key?

Answer (score 0):

My hunch is `UNIQUE` will give you the best performance boost, but `INDEX` would also give a boost.  I think the only reason you wouldn't want to use `UNIQUE` is if you don't want MySQL to handle checking for unique values whenever you do an `INSERT` or an `UPDATE`.

I don't think you need both.  But I'm no expert.