# Mysql Table Key

Tags: mysql, sql, database

Can anyone tell me what is the meaning of  KEY `fk_pickup_method` (`pickup_method_id`),
    KEY `fk_deliv_method` (`delivery_method_id`) lines. As pickup_method and deliv_method are not the tables. So what is the use of these lines.

```
CREATE TABLE `test` (
`idTest` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`Name` mediumtext NOT NULL,
`email` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
`password` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
`firstname` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
`lastname` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
`phone` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL,
`address_street` varchar(128) NOT NULL,
`address_apt` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
`address_city` varchar(128) NOT NULL,
`address_state` varchar(2) NOT NULL,
`address_zip` int(11) NOT NULL,
`fax` bigint(20) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
`account_balance` float NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
`delivery_radius` float DEFAULT NULL,
`pickup_method_id` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
`delivery_method_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
`is_deleted` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
`lat` float NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
`lng` float NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
`timezone` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`idTest`),
UNIQUE KEY `phone_UNIQUE` (`phone`),
KEY `fk_pickup_method` (`pickup_method_id`),
KEY `fk_deliv_method` (`delivery_method_id`)
)
```

Comment: Please remove the `java` tag as this does not seem to relate to Java...

Comment: @ManseUK: Thanks, just did not want to do it myself :-)

Comment: @vikasTheJavaDeveloper: Does this answer your question? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/924265/mysqls-key-keyword

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Line 
`KEY fk_pickup_method (pickup_method_id)`
defines an index **named** `fk_pickup_method` on **table column** `pickup_method_id`.

When you run `EXPLAIN`, under `possible_keys` column you'll see the name of the index.

The usual practice is to call the key as the column it indexes. That's the default behaviour if you don't specify the key name.

Answer (score 4):

They're INDEXes on the columns in the ()'s.  But the fields are not constrained to being UNIQUE.

Look for `{INDEX|KEY}` in this [MySQL document link](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/create-table.html).

Comment: Note: As the NAMEs includes `fk_` they may be INTENDED to be FOREIGN KEYS, but they've been created as INDEXes.

Answer (score 2):

These are indexes on the fields pickup_method_id and delivery_method_id.

How mysql uses indexes : http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/mysql-indexes.html

The name fk_ points to the intention of the creator to create a foreign key. But this is not a foreign key, and won't care about referential integrity for you.

Foreign keys in mysql (innodb) : http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/innodb-foreign-key-constraints.html

Answer (score 1):

My guess is that these were intended to be `FOREIGN KEY` constraints and reference other tables.

InnoDB engine creates an index (if there isn't one) when a `FOREIGN KEY` constraint is defined.

MyISAM engine ignores `FOREIGN KEY` constraints but it still creates the index. Example:

```
CREATE TABLE test 
( test_id int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  delivery_method_id int NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (test_id),
  FOREIGN KEY fk_deliv_method (delivery_method_id)
    REFERENCES delivery_method(delivery_method_id)
) ENGINE=MyISAM 
  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 ;
```

And then:

```
SHOW CREATE TABLE test ;

CREATE TABLE `test` (
  `test_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `delivery_method_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`test_id`),
  KEY `fk_deliv_method` (`delivery_method_id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```