# MySQL "KEY" keyword

Tags: mysql

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `scores` (
  `userID` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `sessionID` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `points` double NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  PRIMARY KEY (`userID`,`sessionID`),
  KEY `par_ind1` (`userID`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

What does the line:

```
KEY `par_ind1` (`userID`)
```

do? (`userID` is a primary key in another table?)

Comment: possible duplicate of [What does the KEY keyword mean?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/924265/what-does-the-key-keyword-mean)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

`KEY` is a synonym for `INDEX`.  This creates an index named `par_ind1` ont the column `userID` in addition to the composite key it already shares with `sessionID`.

See the [MySQL `CREATE TABLE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/create-table.html) documentation for the full details, but the relevant part here is:

```
CREATE [TEMPORARY] TABLE [IF NOT EXISTS] tbl_name
    { LIKE old_tbl_name | (LIKE old_tbl_name) }
create_definition:
    col_name column_definition
  | [CONSTRAINT [symbol]] PRIMARY KEY [index_type] (index_col_name,...)
      [index_option] ...

  /* Key/Index creation */
  | {INDEX|KEY} [index_name] [index_type] (index_col_name,...)
      [index_option] ...
```

Since no `index_type` was specified, the default is used.  See the [`CREATE INDEX` reference](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/create-index.html) for the default index types, which vary by table storage engine. For an InnoDB table such as this, that's a `BTREE` index.

Answer (score 3):

It creates a secondary, non-unique index on this column. You can use `INDEX` and `KEY` interchangeably in this context.