# MySQL - Meaning of "PRIMARY KEY", "UNIQUE KEY" and "KEY" when used together while creating a table

Tags: mysql, sql-server, primary-key, unique-key

Can anyone explain about the purpose of `PRIMARY KEY`, `UNIQUE KEY` and `KEY`, if it is put together in a single `CREATE TABLE` statement in MySQL?

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `tmp` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `uid` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `name` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `tag` int(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `description` varchar(255),
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `uid` (`uid`),
  KEY `name` (`name`),
  KEY `tag` (`tag`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=1 ;
```

How do I convert this query to MSSQL?

Comment: related: [mySQL's KEY keyword?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/924265/697449) Basically `KEY` is synonymous with `INDEX`.

Answer (score 92, accepted):

A key is just a normal index.  A way over simplification is to think of it like a card catalog at a library.  It points MySQL in the right direction.

A unique key is also used for improved searching speed, but it has the constraint that there can be no duplicated items (there are no two x and y where x is not y and x == y).

The [manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/create-index.html) explains it as follows:

> A UNIQUE index creates a constraint such that all values in the index
>   must be distinct. An error occurs if you try to add a new row with a
>   key value that matches an existing row. This constraint does not apply
>   to NULL values except for the BDB storage engine. For other engines, a
>   UNIQUE index permits multiple NULL values for columns that can contain
>   NULL. If you specify a prefix value for a column in a UNIQUE index,
>   the column values must be unique within the prefix.

A primary key is a 'special' unique key.  It basically is a unique key, except that it's used to identify something.

The manual explains how indexes are used in general: [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/mysql-indexes.html).

In MSSQL, the concepts are similar.  There are indexes, unique constraints and primary keys.

Untested, but I believe the MSSQL equivalent is:

```
CREATE TABLE tmp (
  id int NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY IDENTITY,
  uid varchar(255) NOT NULL CONSTRAINT uid_unique UNIQUE,
  name varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  tag int NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
  description varchar(255),
);

CREATE INDEX idx_name ON tmp (name);
CREATE INDEX idx_tag ON tmp (tag);
```

Edit: the code above is tested to be correct; however, I suspect that there's a much better syntax for doing it.  Been a while since I've used SQL server, and apparently I've forgotten quite a bit :).

Comment: Great explanation! The code is working well too. Thank you very much!

Comment: Thank you for pointing me to the correct place in the manual!

Comment: Great!
This link will refer to the typing for MySQL and SQL in the Primary Key thing.
http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_primarykey.asp

Answer (score 29):

Just to add to the other answers, the [documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/create-table.html) gives this explanation:

> - `KEY` is normally a synonym for `INDEX`. The key attribute `PRIMARY KEY` can
>     also be specified as just `KEY` when given in a column definition. This
>     was implemented for compatibility with other database systems.
> - A `UNIQUE` index creates a constraint such that all values in the index
>     must be distinct. An error occurs if you try to add a new row with a
>     key value that matches an existing row. For all engines, a `UNIQUE`
>     index permits multiple `NULL` values for columns that can contain `NULL`.
> - A `PRIMARY KEY` is a unique index where all key columns must be defined
>     as `NOT NULL`. If they are not explicitly declared as `NOT NULL`, MySQL
>     declares them so implicitly (and silently). A table can have only one
>     `PRIMARY KEY`. The name of a `PRIMARY KEY` is always `PRIMARY`, which thus
>     cannot be used as the name for any other kind of index.

Comment: Compatibility with other database systems? What other DBMS uses the word "KEY" for something that isn't a key at all (an index)? I'd always assumed that was just a bit of MySQL strangeness - and that the authors of MySQL don't actually know what a key is :)

Comment: Does each subsequent definition contain all properties of the previous definition. Eg: Is a "UNIQUE KEY" also a "KEY"?

Answer (score 3):

MySQL unique and primary keys serve to identify rows. There can be only one Primary key in a table but one or more unique keys. Key is just index.

for more details you can check http://www.geeksww.com/tutorials/database_management_systems/mysql/tips_and_tricks/mysql_primary_key_vs_unique_key_constraints.php

to convert mysql to mssql try this and see http://gathadams.com/2008/02/07/convert-mysql-to-ms-sql-server/

Comment: @Paul Bellora , your explanation is more clear than mine. Great.

Comment: Well I just quoted the docs, and I didn't see the second part about converting. I think Corbin's answer sums it up well.