# How to save a FirstName of a Person efficiently without duplicate entries

Tags: mysql, duplicates

In my Mysql database, I have a `Person` table which has a key called `FirstName`.

If there are 10000s of entries, sometimes there are repeats of common `FirstNames` of people such as `John` or `Bob` etc.

How can I edit the `Person` table to store the repeats only **once** so that I can utilize memory space and be more efficient at storing data?

Answer (score 2):

You are looking for an extreme form of normalisation that I would classify as micro-optimisation. Most databases I know of do not go that far, but why not after all.

This can be simply achieved by creating a `firstname` table that holds all known first names in your database. Then replace your `firstname` column in your main table by a foreign key reference to this table (typically, a 4-byte `INT`).

the problem with this appraoch is that you will also create an index on `firstname`, which will look something like this:

```
CREATE TABLE fistnames (
    id INT PRIMARY KEY,
    firstname VARCHAR(250)
) ;
```

The footprint of this table would be 4 (`firstnames.id` column) + [length of `firstname`] + [size of primary key index entry]. Also add another 4 bytes for the foreign key in your main table. This is possibly less efficient, storage-wise, than your current structure, especially for those short names such as "Joe".

Comment: that sounds just like what I wanted. Can you put some code up for this example please?

Comment: What about how to implement the condition on how to check for duplicates etc?

Comment: There are [loads of examples out there](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/create-table-foreign-keys.html). Search for "foreign key" or "one to many relationship". To prevent duplicates, add a [unique constraint](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10908676/1446005).

Answer (score 1):

instead of having key on `FirstName`, you should have id as key. Also remove any key from `FirstName` column.

you should think of in terms of `memory versus functionality and speed`.
 If you want to save memory by having a key on `FirstName` column, you will have to sacrifice your functionality of having multiple persons having same name.

You should add an `id` column with primary key on it in `person` table.

As per your request, I am giving you template of person table

```
CREATE TABLE persons
(id int auto_increment primary key, 
FirstName varchar(40),
LastName varchar(40),
details varchar(100),
...any other columns
)
```

if you do not have the `id` field before then use

```
ALTER TABLE persons ADD id int auto_increment primary key;
```

Comment: what if I wanted to have the functionality of having multiple persons having the same name without worrying about memory space?

Comment: just remove the key from `FirstName` and if you have `id` column then make it `primary key`. if no `id` column exists then add it