# MAX() Function with Group by is very slow

Tags: mysql, sql, performance

My query is really slow; It takes 17 seconds to execute. It hits 100% CPU on Godaddy VPS. Any ideas what can be done?

This query:

```
         SELECT
             `gps_unit_location`.`idgps_unit`,
             MAX(`gps_unit_location`.`dt`) dtmax
         FROM `gps_unit_location`
         GROUP BY 1
```

Explain

```
id='1', select type='SIMPLE', table='gps_unit_location', type='index', possible keys=NULL, key='fk_gps2', key len='5', ref=NULL, rows='368668', extra=''
```

Comment: How many records are in the table?

Comment: As explain shows: `rows='368668'`

Comment: How many rows do you get in the output?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An index on `(idgps_unit, dt)` could make the query a lot faster.

You could just extend the index on `idgps_unit`, by changing:

```
KEY `fk_gps2` (`idgps_unit`),
```

to

```
KEY `fk_gps2` (`idgps_unit`, `dt`),
```

(According to [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/924272/50552), `key` is a synonym for `index`.)

Comment: After I add the index, should I run any command to re-index the existing data?

Comment: The database will ensure that indexes are always up to date.  Reindexing is only required if you want to defragment disk space.

Comment: are you sure there's no need for rebuilding statistics?

Comment: @Sebas: A newly created index will have perfect statistics.   Have a look at [this MySQL doc](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/innodb/1.1/en/innodb-other-changes-statistics-estimation.html)

Comment: Hmm this document is unclear. Are you sure of that? I know this is different but under Oracle you ought to rebuild statistics after index creation.

Comment: I added indexes (I changed the create table statement in question); Seems like query went from 17sec to 12sec... Still too slow...

Comment: we're getting into fine tuning now. The next step is to debug the hardware :-(

Comment: This seems to be an issue with Godaddy VPS. I recreated data on my local machine, it takes 1sec to execute.