# check whether product key is already present in database or not?

Tags: php, html, database

I'm having problems with a piece of code. I have a form that submits information to a MySQL database. I already saved product keys in database. I want to check whether key is present in database or not. I'm using following code:

```
    $namecheck = mysql_query("SELECT key FROM license_key WHERE key ='$userEnteredProductKey'");
    $count = mysql_num_rows($namecheck);        
    if($count)
        {
            die("FAILURE - <b>$product_name</b> has <b>NOT</b> been added because the reference number already exists.");
        }
```

if i run program it gives me error as:

```
 Warning: mysql_num_rows() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in code.
```

Hope that makes sense, any help greatly appreciated.

Comment: This means your query returns nothing. Check the query.

Comment: possible duplicate of [mysql\_fetch\_array() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in select](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2973202/mysql-fetch-array-expects-parameter-1-to-be-resource-boolean-given-in-select)

Comment: So which query i have to use?

Comment: Something is missing in your query. check $userEnteredProductKey hold any value. or print your query and check

Comment: You are using [an **obsolete** database API](http://stackoverflow.com/q/12859942/19068) and should use a [modern replacement](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php).  You are probably (we can't see where `$userEnteredProductKey` comes from) **vulnerable to [SQL injection attacks](http://bobby-tables.com/)** that a modern API would make it easier to [defend](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/best-way-to-prevent-sql-injection-in-php) yourself from.

Comment: it holds value because key is entered by user. I want to check that key whether it is present or not

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Insted of using this
    if($count)
try this one,
    if($count == 1)

Answer (score 1):

Try this :

```
$namecheck = mysql_query("SELECT `key` FROM license_key WHERE `key` ='$userEnteredProductKey'");
```

`key` is a reserved keyword in mysql, So better dont use it or wrap it in side `

Ref: [What does the KEY keyword mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/924265/what-does-the-key-keyword-mean)

Answer (score 0):

Use like this

```
$namecheck = mysql_query("SELECT `key` FROM license_key WHERE `key` ='".$userEnteredProductKey."'");
```