# please help me find mysql statement issue

Tags: mysql, sql

```
INSERT INTO person_data('Key','value',Person_id)
SELECT 'aaa','bbb',1, FROM person_data;
```

could someone please indicate what is the issue with the above statement?
is that because 'key' and 'value' are sensitive words? Any help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/924265/what-does-the-key-keyword-mean) is a column name which also happen to be keyword and should not be put inside qoutes but backticks. Also remove last comma in Select list.

```
INSERT INTO person_data 
            ( ` KEY ` , 
             value, 
             person_id) 
SELECT 'aaa', 
       'bbb', 
       1 
FROM   person_data;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
INSERT INTO person_data(`Key`,`value`,`Person_id`) VALUES ('$key', '$value', '$Person_id') 
SELECT *  FROM person_data;
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to quote the column names.
Try this:

```
INSERT INTO person_data(Key,value,Person_id) SELECT 'aaa','bbb',1, FROM person_data;
```