# what is use of 'KEY' in mysql , it is not allowing me edit record in phpmyadmin

Tags: php, mysql, sql, phpmyadmin

Here is my database mapping table definition,
you can try this, when I create this table and add some records in to it, it is not let me edit or delete the records by **phpmyadmin** although by query it should be possible,

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `map2` (
  `map_table_a` varchar(25) DEFAULT NULL,
  `map_id_a` int(10) DEFAULT NULL,
  `map_table_b` varchar(25) DEFAULT NULL,
  `map_id_b` int(10) DEFAULT NULL,
 KEY `map_table_b` (`map_table_b`,`map_id_b`),
 KEY `map_table_a` (`map_table_a`,`map_id_a`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

I don't know reason behind this behavior

Comment: @Manwal I don't know, people are saying it is equal to INDEX in mysql

Comment: See this: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/optimization-indexes.html

Comment: @Manwal Sir I know index,  But my actual question is why I can't edit records by PHPMYADMIN ,
you can try to create this table and check

Comment: You can see this post:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/924265/what-does-the-key-keyword-mean

Comment: @HardikPatel my question is different then "What does the KEY keyword mean?"

Comment: @ChintanGor define a `Primary Key` in your table. Then you will able to edit record from Phpmyadmin.

Comment: Reopened due to absolutely not being a duplicate of the marked question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Depending on your phpMyAdmin version, you should see this error message:

[image: This table does not contain a unique column. Grid edit, checkbox, Edit, Copy and Delete features are not available.]

While you do have `KEY` columns, you have no `PRIMARY` or `UNIQUE` columns defined. This is why phpMyAdmin cannot edit your data - it has no way to be sure it is editing the correct row.

Suggested solution: Add the following into your table definition, preferably as the first column:

```
`id` INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY
```