# What means ADD key(column) in mysql sintax

Tags: mysql, key

To better understand my question what Add key means in this situation:

ALTER TABLE productvariants
    ADD PRIMARY KEY (variantId),
    ADD KEY (buyPrice),
    ADD KEY (productCode);

Comment: well... it means please mysql ADD a KEY on that column...

Comment: Indeed, but by that KEY  means add an index on those 2 columns?

Comment: Seriously man, there are plenty of ressources out there, your wasting your time and ours asking such questions here...

Comment: I didn't meant to waste anyone's time, i just wanted a direct answer  because i thought here is  the right place to get.

Comment: But if that's the case i will search on the web some more.

Comment: It seems you didn't put a lot of time searching : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/924265/what-does-the-key-keyword-mean