# How do I get a Map<String, Integer> from MyBatis? Cause: java.sql.SQLException: Invalid value for getInt() - 'NONE'

Tags: mybatis, spring-mybatis

I tried to follow [Return HashMap in mybatis and use it as ModelAttribute in spring MVC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11913013/return-hashmap-in-mybatis-and-use-it-as-modelattribute-in-spring-mvc) (Option 1) and [Mybatis ResultMap is HashMap<String,Object>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36400538/mybatis-resultmap-is-hashmapstring-object). I have

```
@Select("select sources.host as 'key', count(*) total ... group by host")
@MapKey("key")
Map<String, Integer> getSourcesById(@Param("id")String id, @Param("hitDate")Date hitDate);
```

It returns an error

> Error attempting to get column 'key' from result set.  Cause: java.sql.SQLException: Invalid value for getInt() - 'NONE'
>       ; SQL []; Invalid value for getInt() - 'NONE'; nested exception is java.sql.SQLException: Invalid value for getInt() - 'NONE'

The query works fine in MySQL and returns

```
| key         | total |
+-------------+-------+
| NONE        |    33 |
| twitter.com |     1 |
```

It's as if it is not using the `@MapKey` annotation.

---

I tried

```
List<AbstractMap.SimpleEntry<String, Integer>> getSourcesById(...)
```

But it gave

> nested exception is org.apache.ibatis.executor.ExecutorException: No constructor found in java.util.AbstractMap$SimpleEntry matching [java.lang.String, java.lang.Long]

Also tried this with the same error.

```
List<AbstractMap.SimpleEntry<String, Long>>
```

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/AbstractMap.SimpleEntry.html#constructor_summary

MyBatis 3.4.6, MyBatis-Spring 1.3.2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to build my own class, but I don't like it. It's dumb that I have to add so much code for getting a simple key/value pair from the DB.

`Pair.java`

```
public class Pair<T1, T2> {
    public T1 key;
    public T2 value;

    public Pair(T1 k, T2 v) {
        key = k;
        value = v;
    }
    
    public Pair(String k, Long v) {
        key = (T1) k;
        value = (T2) v;
    }

    public T1 getKey() {
        return key;
    }

    public T2 getValue() {
        return value;
    }

}
```

`Mapper.java`

```
List<Pair<String, Long>> getSourcesById(@Param("id")String id, @Param("hitDate")Date hitDate);
```

`Page.jsp`

```
<c:forEach items="${sources}" var="s">${s.value},</c:forEach>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should write the following,

```
@Select("select sources.host as 'key', count(*) total ... group by host")
@MapKey("key")
Map<String, Map<String, Object>> getSourcesById(@Param("id")String id, @Param("hitDate")Date hitDate);
```

It's the option-1's way.

Comment: That is a Map of Maps. Why would that be useful? And how would you specify the 2 keys? There are only 2 values, but that requires 3. Presumably you would use the same key for the outer Map as the inner Map, but then what's the point? Might as well just use a List of Maps at that point.

Comment: @Chloe It's the way that option 1 works, for key "NONE" of the outter map, inner map is "key" -> "NONE", "total" -> 33. You can transform Map<String, Map<String, Object>> to Map<String, Integer> by `Map<String, Integer> anotherMap = map.entrySet().stream()
                .collect(Collectors.toMap(Map.Entry::getKey, it -> (int)it.getValue().get("total")));`